# how to create a select statement with 2 foreign keys in one table pointing to two different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have 3 tables and one of the tables (itemtag) has two columns each a foreign key pointing to each of the other 2 tables (item and tag). I'm trying to find out how to create a single select statement against this table containing fk's using values that correspond to one of the other tables.

**Table:** item

```
| itemid   | name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | chair          |
| 2        | table          |
```

**Table:** tag

```
| tagid    | name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 10       | kitchen        |
| 11       | bedroom        |
```

**Table:** itemtag

```
| itemid (fk to item.itemid)  | tagid (fk to tag.tagid)  |
| --------------------------- | ------------------------ |
| 1                           | 10                       |
| 2                           | 10                       |
| 2                           | 11                       |
```

what is the proper way to query the itemtag table for a given name (like chair) or tag (like kitchen) that correlates values in the given item or tag tables? I have this statement that is producing the expected results as far as i can tell but is this really the correct way and/or actually producing accurate output?

```
select item.name
FROM item, tag, itemtag
WHERE itemtag.itemid = item.itemid
AND itemtag.tagid = tag.tagid
AND tag.name = 'kitchen'
```

In this example im expecting item names that have a tag of "kitchen".

Comment: The query is fine. Alternatively you you use join statements, which I personally find a bit more readable, but that's purely as matter of taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking  at your query, It seems It must be producing accurate output.

But you should consider using standard ANSI join as follows:

```
select item.name, tag.name
  FROM itemtag join item on itemtag.itemid = item.itemid
  JOIN tag on itemtag.tagid = tag.tagid
 WHERE tag.name = 'kitchen'
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you..  I did try a few join statements but it kept erroring out so i think i had the wrong syntax

Comment: You can accept this answer if it solved your issue so that this question is marked as resolved.